# R - Deleting rows from one data set which are present in another data set

Tags: r

In R I have two data sets, one which has all the data lets call this data set LARGE, where we have one column labelled idnumber. The other data set which has specific data records from LARGE is a reduced version due to criteria that I have made which also has the column labelled idnumber. 
What I would like to do is from the data set ‘LARGE’ I would like to exclude from it all data records which have the same idnumber which appears in the reduced version.
This is what I have thought of: unmatched <- LARGE[which(LARGE$idnumber not in reduced$idnumber)] but I don't know how to code 'not in’ in R

Comment: Would something like unmatched <- LARGE[which(LARGE$idnumber != reduced$idnumber)] work?

Comment: unmatched <- large[!large$idnumber %in% reduced$idnumber, ]

Answer (score 1):

You are describing an anti-join

```
library(dplyr)

LARGE <- data.frame(idnumber = 1:100, Y = rnorm(100))
reduced <- LARGE[sample(nrow(LARGE), 42),]

unmatched <- anti_join(LARGE, reduced)
```

And to use a "not in" binary function in general, you can apply the following function:

```
`%notin%` <- function(x,y) !(x %in% y)
3 %notin% c(3,5)
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

following Coles answer, google the "R not in operator"

Easiest way:

```
data [!(data %in% large$idnubmer),]
```

so the %in% finds all the cases where they match. the ! at the start 'negates' that .. ie: finds where they don't.